# Switch behind router or router behind switch

Tags: networking

I have a Dlink DGS 1100-24P SWITCH and ASUS (RT-AC68U) Wireless-AC1900 Dual-Band Gigabit Router to install, Which is the better option, switch behind a router or the switch before the router

Comment: That depends on what you're trying to achieve. Are you using the router for DHCP and NAT? The switch itself won't handle allocating IP addresses so would need to be AFTER the router. What are you trying to dp?

Comment: Hi Jonno its a small guest house and I am trying to bring wired and wireless internet connection to the rooms as well as setting up printer, computers and security cameras.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming a normal residential setup, you need to put the switch after the router.

Most cable and DSL modems will only talk to the first device that speaks to it, until the modem is rebooted, regardless whether that first device is directly connected or connected by way of a switch.  So you can't do something like this:

Cable Modem -> Switch -> Multiple Computers And/Or Router

because the modem will only talk to the first computer that talks to it.  To share the connection, you need a router.  Thus, you usually want that "first device" to be a router.

Cable Modem -> Router -> Switch -> Multiple Computers.

If your cable modem has a built-in router, then of course your first two devices are automatically "Cable Modem -> Router" and you don't really need your own router.

---

Note that the LAN ports on the back of your ASUS router are actually a switch - the router part of the device is "between" the LAN ports and WAN port.  So you can't connect your cable or DSL modem to a LAN port - you'll be in the same situation as using a switch above.

Comment: Hi Lawrence C.  its a fiber optic service, to a small guest house and I am trying to bring wired and wireless internet connection to the rooms as well as setting up printer, computers and security cameras

Comment: I imagine your ISP gave you a box where the fiber connects and then on the other side is a single Ethernet port?  It probably works the same way as a cable modem above.

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: yes Lawrence that's correct

Comment: ISP Box -> Router -> then switch.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence, i am hooked up can u explain to me why switch lights  when i connect a Ethernet cord into the switch the light is orange instead of solid green

Comment: Possibly it's 10Mbps or 100Mbps instead of 1000Mbps.

Comment: Is this determined by the ISP or it depend on the equipment. The equipment Its a Gigabit Router and a Gigabit switch.

Comment: When configuring  the ROUTER and the SWITCH LAN side , should  i leave their default Gateways or do they need to share the same gateway.

Comment: The IP/default gateway for the switch is for the management interface/functions only.  The switch's default gateway should be your router's IP.

Comment: Also what the lights mean depends on the equipment.